# Iteration ng-repeat only n times in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list contains 20 transactions. The requirement is,using ng-repeat when I click the button 5 transactions should append again when I click the button next 5 transactions should append and so on..

can anyone plz help on this.....

thanx

Comment: Add some code that we can see please

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use the limitTo function in your ng-repeat to only show 5 on load:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 5">
     <p>{{item.id}}</p>
 </div>
```

Then, on your button, increment the limitTo to display the next 5:

```
 <button ng-click="limitTo = limitTo + 5">Increase</button>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

@Oam Thankuu.. your code helped me a lot to find the exact solution.

here is the solution..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: count">
 <p>{{item.id}}</p>
```

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 5" ng-init="count=5">Increase</button>
```

Comment: Add an ng-class directive, checking the count variable (count >= maxItems) and enable a class that hides the button in this case

Comment: can anybody help me to get the count of ng-repeat

I need how much time ng-repeat is iterating over